# No route in the route table matches the supplied values

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho as seguintes configurações de rotas:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Perfil Administrador, Master")]
        public ActionResult AlterarHospital(int id, string url)
        {
            var rota = url.Split('/').ToArray();
            string[] routes = { rota[rota.Length - 1], rota[rota.Length - 2], rota[rota.Length - 3] };

            if (routes[0].Contains("?"))
            {
                //Limpar URL
                routes[0] = routes[0].Remove(routes[0].IndexOf("?"), routes[0].Length - routes[0].IndexOf("?"));
            }

            //Alterar Hospital Logado para que o administrador possa visualizar dados de outros hospitais 
            var hospital = _hospitalService.GetById(id);
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Usuario"];
            cookie.Values.Set("HospitalId", hospital.HospitalId.ToString());
            cookie.Values.Set("HospitalNome", Server.UrlEncode(hospital.hospital));
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

            return RedirectToAction(routes[0], routes[1], new { area = routes[2] });
        }
```

Estou fazendo uma troca de hospitais puxando o ID do hospital, quando eu troco a primeira vez de hospital do ID 1 para o ID 2 funciona, mais quando eu vou alterar de novo ele aparece o seguinte erro:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Quais rotas você está tentando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public ActionResult AlterarHospital(int id)
        {            
            //Alterar Hospital Logado para que o administrador possa visualizar dados de outros hospitais 
            var hospital = _hospitalService.GetById(id);
            Cookies.SetCookie("hid", hospital.HospitalId.ToString());
            Cookies.SetCookie("hname", Server.UrlEncode(hospital.hospital));

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cadastro", new { area = "Formulario" });
        }
```

Resolvi!